# Proving that there are no other solutions to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}-3\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+2y=0$$
How can I prove that $y=c_1e^x+c_2e^{2x}$ is the only solution (or most general solution) to this differential equation?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the mean value theorem from calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Show that the differential equation can be written as
$$
             e^{2x}\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^{-x}\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}y)\right]=0.
$$
This form of the equation can be integrated directly.

Answer (score 0):

The most general solution to a 2nd order differential equation has 2 arbitrary constants and $e^x$ and $e^{2x}$ are [linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23139/proof-of-linear-independence-of-eat) so they form a basis for all solutions. (Adding another function of $x$ that is independent of both $e^x$ and $e^{2x}$ would involve a third arbitrary constant.)